# Intercept specific function invocations using parent/child classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, oop, design-patterns

I am writing a framework that allows us to intercept certain function invocations so that we can manage them(enforce timeouts and retries， persist return values etc.). Right now I'm thinking of introducing an abstract class with a method that invokes an abstract method and forcing users/clients to inherit the abstract class and do their function invocations inside the abstract method.

Specifically, I am writing an abstract class `Fruit` that expects clients to:

1. Extend `Fruit` and override the `eat_fruit` method
2. Invoke the `eat` method when actually wanting to use the overriden `eat_fruit` method

The reason I'm thinking of doing this is that we want to record the number of eat_fruit invocations

```
class Fruit:
    def eat(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.eat_fruit(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def eat_fruit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class Apple(Fruit):
    def eat_fruit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Eat Apple")
        
apple = Apple()
apple.eat()
```

However, we're running into a problem with extensibility. Let's say the client needs to add input parameter `color` to Apple's `eat_fruit` method, they can add it like this:

```
class Fruit:
    def eat(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.eat_fruit(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def eat_fruit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class Apple(Fruit):
    def eat_fruit(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Eat "+ color + " Apple")
        
apple = Apple()
apple.eat("Red")
```

This is workable but relies on them knowing that `Fruit`'s `eat` method passes `*args` and `**kwargs` directly to the `eat_fruit` method, which seems to be an implementation detail in the `eat` method that may be subject to change.

I'm wondering if there are better ways to accomplish the same thing. In particular,

1. Is it possible for them to invoke `eat_fruit` directly(rather than invoking the parent class's `eat` method and assume that the arguments will be forwarded to `eat_fruit`)? I can't think of a way for them to do that while still letting us keep track of `eat_fruit` invocations
2. Is there a better way(rather than using parent-child classes) to intercept function invocations? The final goal of this framework is to intercept specific function invocations made by clients so that we can manage them(enforce timeouts and retries， persist return values etc.).

Thanks!
Jessica

Comment: Is the user going to be aware of timeout enforcement/retries/etc?

Comment: @C.Nivs yes they will be aware of it. Ideally they can set it somewhere as well

Comment: Maybe a decorator pattern would fit here nicely. it's explicit and the behavior is easy to apply to functions in the class. Something like `@enforce_timeout(seconds)` or `@count_invocations`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, frameworks and APIs solve this via an [Event-driven architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture).

While other methods might solve your problems, like with decorators, if you want full control over what is happening, you can consider this architecture.

Basically, instead of executing functions directly, you "fire" or "invoke" an "event" that is associated with that function, but which also  can be associated with multiple functions. The user can have their own functions, and the framework can have its own functions, without either party having to know too much about the other. The user is happy that his functions are executing, and the framework is happy to have control over any event that is fired or invoked.

However this is not a small feature that a framework can have, especially if you are implementing it from scratch. So when considering to provide this feature in your framework, it is worth checking if the language you are using already has support for it or if a 3rd party library is available that can provide this feature for you.

Comment: One of our requirements is to allow users to write any arbitrary code though. How would an event driven architecture enable that?

Comment: @Jessica What do you mean by "arbitrary code"?